# How to pass server properties to a route.js api using nextjs app router

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I have a nextjs app with a custom server.js that reads some config settings from a config file on startup. I would like to pass some of these properties along with a session key that gets read on startup to a local api that can then be used from one of the client pages. I'm using the app router and have the api route.js file working but I can't figure out the correct way of passing these properties over from the server to the route.js file. I tried some static properties on a config helper file but these were undefined when I tried to read them from the route.js file.

I tried some static properties on a config helper file but these were undefined when I tried to read them from the route.js file.